# Получить определенные данные с JSON

Tags: python, json

Я пишу на python и не совсем до конца понимаю как именно я могу получить данные с JSON.

Я использую:

```py
url = 'https://shikimori.org/api/animes/'
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
getJson = json.loads(r.text)
```

И мне нужно получить `"russian"` из `"genres"`

Полный JSON-код.

```
{
  "id": 37450,
  "name": "Seishun Buta Yarou wa Bunny Girl Senpai no Yume wo Minai",
  "russian": "Этот глупый свин не понимает мечту девочки-зайки",
  "image": {
    "original": "/system/animes/original/37450.jpg?1606451843",
    "preview": "/system/animes/preview/37450.jpg?1606451843",
    "x96": "/system/animes/x96/37450.jpg?1606451843",
    "x48": "/system/animes/x48/37450.jpg?1606451843"
  },
  "url": "/animes/z37450-seishun-buta-yarou-wa-bunny-girl-senpai-no-yume-wo-minai",
  "kind": "tv",
  "score": "8.33",
  "status": "released",
  "episodes": 13,
  "episodes_aired": 13,
  "aired_on": "2018-10-04",
  "released_on": "2018-12-27",
  "rating": "pg_13",
  "english": [
    "Rascal Does Not Dream of Bunny Girl Senpai"
  ],
  "japanese": [
    "青春ブタ野郎はバニーガール先輩の夢を見ない"
  ],
  "synonyms": [
    "Эта глупая свинья не понимает мечту девочки-зайки!"
  ],
  "license_name_ru": "Негодник, которому не снилась девушка-кролик",
  "duration": 24,
  "description": "Ничем не примечательный школьник Сакута Адзусагава проводит всё своё свободное время в библиотеке. Однажды он встречает девушку в костюме кролика, которая старше его на год. Она представляется как Маи Сакурадзима — прославленная актриса и первая красавица школы. Девушка рассказывает, что все вокруг перестали «видеть» её, поэтому она оделась так вызывающе. По мнению Маи, всё это из-за загадочного «подросткового синдрома». Адзусагава, недолго думая, решает помочь Сакурадзиме в решении этой странной проблемы. Однако кто мог знать, чем это обернётся...",
  "description_html": "<div class=\"b-text_with_paragraphs\">Ничем не примечательный школьник <a href=\"https://shikimori.org/characters/118733-sakuta-azusagawa\" title=\"Sakuta Azusagawa\" class=\"bubbled b-link\" data-tooltip_url=\"https://shikimori.org/characters/118733-sakuta-azusagawa/tooltip\" data-attrs=\"{&quot;id&quot;:118733,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;character&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Sakuta Azusagawa&quot;,&quot;russian&quot;:&quot;Сакута Адзусагава&quot;}\">Сакута Адзусагава</a> проводит всё своё свободное время в библиотеке. Однажды он встречает девушку в костюме кролика, которая старше его на год. Она представляется как <a href=\"https://shikimori.org/characters/118739-mai-sakurajima\" title=\"Mai Sakurajima\" class=\"bubbled b-link\" data-tooltip_url=\"https://shikimori.org/characters/118739-mai-sakurajima/tooltip\" data-attrs=\"{&quot;id&quot;:118739,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;character&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Mai Sakurajima&quot;,&quot;russian&quot;:&quot;Маи Сакурадзима&quot;}\">Маи Сакурадзима</a> — прославленная актриса и первая красавица школы. Девушка рассказывает, что все вокруг перестали «видеть» её, поэтому она оделась так вызывающе. По мнению <a href=\"https://shikimori.org/characters/118739-mai-sakurajima\" title=\"Mai Sakurajima\" class=\"bubbled b-link\" data-tooltip_url=\"https://shikimori.org/characters/118739-mai-sakurajima/tooltip\" data-attrs=\"{&quot;id&quot;:118739,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;character&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Mai Sakurajima&quot;,&quot;russian&quot;:&quot;Маи Сакурадзима&quot;}\">Маи</a>, всё это из-за загадочного «подросткового синдрома». <a href=\"https://shikimori.org/characters/118733-sakuta-azusagawa\" title=\"Sakuta Azusagawa\" class=\"bubbled b-link\" data-tooltip_url=\"https://shikimori.org/characters/118733-sakuta-azusagawa/tooltip\" data-attrs=\"{&quot;id&quot;:118733,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;character&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Sakuta Azusagawa&quot;,&quot;russian&quot;:&quot;Сакута Адзусагава&quot;}\">Адзусагава</a>, недолго думая, решает помочь <a href=\"https://shikimori.org/characters/118739-mai-sakurajima\" title=\"Mai Sakurajima\" class=\"bubbled b-link\" data-tooltip_url=\"https://shikimori.org/characters/118739-mai-sakurajima/tooltip\" data-attrs=\"{&quot;id&quot;:118739,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;character&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Mai Sakurajima&quot;,&quot;russian&quot;:&quot;Маи Сакурадзима&quot;}\">Сакурадзиме</a> в решении этой странной проблемы. Однако кто мог знать, чем это обернётся...</div>",
  "description_source": null,
  "franchise": "seishun_buta_yarou_wa_yumemiru_shoujo_no_yume_wo_minai",
  "favoured": false,
  "anons": false,
  "ongoing": false,
  "thread_id": 243632,
  "topic_id": 243632,
  "myanimelist_id": 37450,
  "rates_scores_stats": [
    {
      "name": 10,
      "value": 15568
    },
    {
      "name": 9,
      "value": 11661
    },
    {
      "name": 8,
      "value": 11069
    },
    {
      "name": 7,
      "value": 5751
    },
    {
      "name": 6,
      "value": 2201
    },
    {
      "name": 5,
      "value": 962
    },
    {
      "name": 4,
      "value": 441
    },
    {
      "name": 3,
      "value": 198
    },
    {
      "name": 2,
      "value": 134
    },
    {
      "name": 1,
      "value": 228
    }
  ],
  "rates_statuses_stats": [
    {
      "name": "Запланировано",
      "value": 24671
    },
    {
      "name": "Просмотрено",
      "value": 78137
    },
    {
      "name": "Смотрю",
      "value": 8472
    },
    {
      "name": "Брошено",
      "value": 2687
    },
    {
      "name": "Отложено",
      "value": 1573
    }
  ],
  "updated_at": "2021-07-29T00:09:43.219+03:00",
  "next_episode_at": null,
  "fansubbers": [
    "MedusaSub",
    "AniPlay",
    "AniDate",
    "SovetRomantica",
    "Risens Team",
    "Wakanim"
  ],
  "fandubbers": [
    "AniLibria",
    "AniStar",
    "AniMedia",
    "FRONDA & AniNya",
    "AniZeit",
    "AniMaunt",
    "Wakanim",
    "AniFilm",
    "AniDUB",
    "BeyBeast project",
    "FinalVoice",
    "Onibaku Group"
  ],
  "licensors": [
    "Wakanim"
  ],
  "genres": [
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Comedy",
      "russian": "Комедия",
      "kind": "anime"
    },
    {
      "id": 37,
      "name": "Supernatural",
      "russian": "Сверхъестественное",
      "kind": "anime"
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "name": "Drama",
      "russian": "Драма",
      "kind": "anime"
    },
    {
      "id": 22,
      "name": "Romance",
      "russian": "Романтика",
      "kind": "anime"
    },
    {
      "id": 23,
      "name": "School",
      "russian": "Школа",
      "kind": "anime"
    }
  ],
  "studios": [
    {
      "id": 1835,
      "name": "CloverWorks",
      "filtered_name": "CloverWorks",
      "real": false,
      "image": "/system/studios/original/1835.png?1545379956"
    }
  ],
  "videos": [
    {
      "id": 23765,
      "url": "https://youtu.be/qbVs----INw",
      "image_url": "http://img.youtube.com/vi/qbVs----INw/hqdefault.jpg",
      "player_url": "http://youtube.com/embed/qbVs----INw",
      "name": "Seishun Buta Yarou wa Bunny Girl Senpai no Yume wo Minai - PV1",
      "kind": "pv",
      "hosting": "youtube"
    },
    {
      "id": 23967,
      "url": "https://youtube.com/watch?v=TukSCWAYQno",
      "image_url": "http://img.youtube.com/vi/TukSCWAYQno/hqdefault.jpg",
      "player_url": "http://youtube.com/embed/TukSCWAYQno",
      "name": "[SS] PV1 озвучка Seishun Buta Yarou wa Bunny Girl Senpai no Yume wo Minai",
      "kind": "pv",
      "hosting": "youtube"
    }
  ],
  "screenshots": [
    {
      "original": "/system/screenshots/original/d3996f9a5b9177abc7ac47078f41c18b2bbf1b99.png?1538659796",
      "preview": "/system/screenshots/x332/d3996f9a5b9177abc7ac47078f41c18b2bbf1b99.jpg?1538659796"
    },
    {
      "original": "/system/screenshots/original/6fd5172dc9d691f936e380a44045d0ce88404039.png?1538659810",
      "preview": "/system/screenshots/x332/6fd5172dc9d691f936e380a44045d0ce88404039.jpg?1538659810"
    }
  ],
  "user_rate": null
}
```

Буду рад любой помощи! Спасибо большое.

Comment: `json.loads(r.text)` не нужно, можете написать просто `r.json()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Пример:***

```py
from shikimori_api import Shikimori

session = Shikimori()
api = session.get_api()
anime = api.animes(37450).GET()

russian_genres = [genre['russian'] for genre in anime['genres']]
print(russian_genres)
```

***stdout:***

```py
['Комедия', 'Сверхъестественное', 'Драма', 'Романтика', 'Школа']
```

---

**P.S.:** Пользуясь случаем, рекламирую Вам библиотеку [`shikimori_api`](https://github.com/nomnoms12/shikimori_api), которую я сам написал для удобной работы с API Shikimori.

Comment: Большое спасибо за такую библиотеку.

Answer (score 0):

```
russians = []
for n in getJson['genres']:
   russians.append(n['russian'])
```